# AWS Cloudfront some images still served from origin. x-cache: Miss from cloudfront

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I am using AWS cloudfront with the origin pointing to AWS load balancer. Cloudfront is redirecting HTTP to HTTPS. ELB is listening on HTTP only.

I have added this to nginx.

```
# Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
location ~* \.
(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
 expires 2M;
 access_log off;
 add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# CSS and Javascript
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
 expires 1y;
 access_log off;
 add_header Cache-Control "public"; 
}
```

Some images are getting it from CF but some are not. I don't know why.

### x-cache: Hit from cloudfront

```
curl -X GET -I https://test.ewhale.co/media/cache/attachment/resize/1296/product_gallery_main/5a6bf25ea84a0572610265.jpeg
```

### x-cache: Miss from cloudfront

```
curl -X GET -I https://test.ewhale.co/media/cache/attachment/resize/914/product_gallery_main/5a6b9f07983ca610410692.png
```

Here is my CR configuration. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: I cleared the CF cache. It worked now.

Comment: Sorry, the problem persists. Clearing the cache worked some images. Not all. Also, response time is still very slow. Is there anything else I should look for?

Comment: You should not be forwarding cookies for a cache behavior that handles images, which means you probably should not be running images through your default cache behavior.  This will dramatically reduce your hit ratio to almost nothing, and make your `curl` test pretty much meaningless.

Comment: I have changed forward cookies to none. But I still get `x-cache: Miss from cloudfront`. One image will get hint another is miss. `curl -X GET -I https://test.ewhale.co/media/a.jpg`

Comment: I'll take a look at that image and see if I can observe anything.